# JDBC SQL : if statement string == char.toString not working. :)

Tags: sql, database, string, jdbc, if-statement

How come my if statement `if (tablename == Character.toString('S'))` is not registering as true? Both print out the be S... Is there a different why I can implement this? I could do a != but I need to add more arguments to my if statement, and my tablename needs to stay a string.

```
System.out.println("Enter table:");
String line = input.readLine();
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(line);
String tablename = tk.nextToken();

DatabaseMetaData d = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rm = d.getColumns(null, null, tablename, null);

System.out.println(tablename);
System.out.println(Character.toString('S');
 System.out.println(tablename == Character.toString('S');

if (tablename == Character.toString('S')){
  System.out.println("Woot!");
}
```

OUTPUT: 
Enter table: 
 S
 S
 S 
 false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're comparing both objects for equality, you need to use:

```
if (tablename.equals(Character.toString('S'))) {
   ...
```

Here's a nice reference on equality comparison in java:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed, knew it was something simple I was missing. Appreciate it <3

Comment: A closing parens is missing :)

Answer (score 0):

The == only relates to the equality of the pointer that Character.toString() returns.  Need to use the below.

```
tablename.equals(Character.toString('s'))
```